# Reset AppBarLayout collapsed state with animation

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

In my first screen, my `AppBarLayout` has scrolling behavior. But on the second screen, i reset the scrolled state of the `AppBarLayout` by calling `setExpanded(true, true)`. Now what i want to achieve that when i return to the first screen, i want to animate back to the scrolled state of the appbar which was on the first screen.

I did not manage to do this, but found two workarounds.

**First:**

```
appBar.setExpanded(false, true);
```

This will fully collapse the appbar with animation, but i want to collapse it only to the percentage that was before.

**Second:**

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar;
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();

toolbarState = behavior.onSaveInstanceState(coordinatorLayout, appBar); // in onDestroyView
...
behavior.onRestoreInstanceState(coordinatorLayout, appBar, toolbarState); // in onViewCreated
```

This will scroll to the correct percentage, but will not use animation.

I also tried to call [`onNestedFling`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior.html#onNestedFling(android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout,%20android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout,%20android.view.View,%20float,%20float,%20boolean)), but that always fully collapsed the appbar.

Is there any way to achieve this?